# Store the User information in a object on each load or grab the info when action is made

Tags: php

I have a Session which contain the "user id"

I have some information stored in the user table (that I need to grab)
The question is If I should grab all data and put it in a object on each request or just make the query when an action is made?

Example #1

```
//Update Password

//a user object contain all data from users table...

if ($user->password == $new_password) {
    $errors[] = 'You can\'t choose the same password!';
}
```

Example #2

```
//Update Password

//$current_password = query password and fetch

if ($current_password == $new_password) {
//...
}
```

Etc...

Answer (score 0):

For simple projects, it is best to put that data in a "user object", in the session. But, only place data in that object that is not subject to rapid change, such as their username, userid, privilege level, etc.

More to the point, do not keep the user's password hash in the session, and especially do not store the user's password in plaintext in your database or in the session data. By the looks of it, I believe you may be doing just that.

Instead, use a [hash function](http://php.net/hash) to secure the password data from reversibility.

Comment: Nope. The session only contain USER ID. The thing I am asking whetever I should pull ALL the data from a query in to a object (on every page request = I've seen other scripts doing that OR If I should just grab, on an action made, look examples above please